# ORACLE - Merge statement, update when match and destiny values are null

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have a merge statement, I need to update several columns just when destiny table has null values in these columns.
If x column is null in destiny update just that one. If just 2 columns in destiny are null, update just these 2 columns.
How to validate each column is update or not, checking if in destiny is null?

```
 MERGE INTO all_weather_mv p
              USING (SELECT 
                    a.ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F
                   ,a.ACTUAL_DEW_POINT_F
                   ,a.ACTUAL_WIND_SPEED_MPH
                   ,a.ACTUAL_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_PCT
                   ,a.ACTUAL_STATION_PRESSURE_IN
                   ,a.ACTUAL_HOURLY_PRECIP_IN
                   ,a.OBJECTID
                   ,a.DATETIME_UTC
               FROM gtt_all_weather_mv  a
                   ,wx_stations        w
               WHERE w.OBJECTID      = a.OBJECTID
               AND w.WX_PREFERENCE = 1) d
               ON (p.OBJECTID     = d.OBJECTID
               AND p.DATETIME_UTC = d.DATETIME_UTC
            )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET p.ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F=d.ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F,
                p.ACTUAL_DEW_POINT_F=d.ACTUAL_DEW_POINT_F,
                p.ACTUAL_WIND_SPEED_MPH=d.ACTUAL_WIND_SPEED_MPH,
                p.ACTUAL_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_PCT=d.ACTUAL_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_PCT,
                p.ACTUAL_STATION_PRESSURE_IN=d.ACTUAL_STATION_PRESSURE_IN,
                p.ACTUAL_HOURLY_PRECIP_IN=d.ACTUAL_HOURLY_PRECIP_IN              
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
          INSERT ( 
                  OBJECTID,
                  DATETIME_UTC, 
                  ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F, 
                  ACTUAL_DEW_POINT_F,
                  ACTUAL_WIND_SPEED_MPH,
                  ACTUAL_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_PCT, 
                  ACTUAL_STATION_PRESSURE_IN,
                  ACTUAL_HOURLY_PRECIP_IN
                 )
VALUES (    d.OBJECTID,
            d.DATETIME_UTC,
            d.ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F, 
            d.ACTUAL_DEW_POINT_F,
            d.ACTUAL_WIND_SPEED_MPH,
            d.ACTUAL_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY_PCT, 
            d.ACTUAL_STATION_PRESSURE_IN,
            d.ACTUAL_HOURLY_PRECIP_IN
        )
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NVL` function, e.g.

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET p.ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F = nvl(p.ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F, d.ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F),
```

which says: if `p.ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F` is empty (i.e. `NULL`), then put `d.ACTUAL_DRY_BULB_TEMP_F` into it.

The same goes for all other columns.